# Why there's no need of linking against UIKit.framework or Foundation.framework?

Tags: ios, xcode, uikit, foundation

Why this two frameworks can be used in any iOS App, but there's no need to link against them? I am assuming that when the App is build they are added as a dependency automatically, but how does this process work and how does Xcode decide this? I have never seen any configuration in build settings or build phases that includes this automatically.

And also, if is added automatically (or if is just part of the iOS SDK core), why you can also add them manually (in Build Phases)? Is there any case when you actually need to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it seems is because `Link Frameworks Automatically` is set to `YES`, and this will automatically add any referenced framework that supports modules.